# How to add a separate test project to my application in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows

I have a windows 8 app project developed in Visual Studio 2012. Now I would like to write a separate test project and remotely test some functionality without getting into the apps source code. This saparete project should be able to give some input to the main project and also track the output as well. (In this case I think I might have to expose some of those methods in the app to be used externally)

I have this fuzzy idea but Im not sure how exactly to implement it. Any clues about the possibility of it and if yes how can I do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean a unit test project? Or a UI test project?

Comment: Now I see that there is something called 'generic test' in Visual Studio. Im looking into it.